# Osm map imported to Arangodb

Tags: openstreetmap, arangodb

I am new to arangodb. I am going to use arangodb to perform algorithms on a road network.

I found this https://github.com/arangodb-helper/osm-2-graph?files=1

I tried to import the edges file, vertices file into arangodb using `arangoimp` (in json format).

But I could see only single node always. It doesn't get  expand after clicking expand button. Full network view only shows nodes, no edges.

Could you give correct steps with commands? Seems I have trapped somewhere.

I used Monaco osm map. Using arangodb 3.2 version

**Edit 1:**
my commands as follows

```
arangoimp --file V-CA.json --collection vertices --create-collection true --type json
> created:          1896 warnings/errors:  0 updated/replaced: 0
> ignored:          0

arangoimp --file E-CA.json --collection edges --create-collection true --type json --create-collection-type edge
> created:          256 warnings/errors:  0 updated/replaced: 0 ignored:
> 0
```

OSM to graph file conversion

```
python convert-pbf.py monaco.osm
```

**Edit 2**

I observed same results after using 3.3.7

I saw it shows

```
> 250 nodes 0 0 edges
```

at he botton after "Load full graph". But at the import it shows  1896 vertices. Is it showing part of vertices only?

Comment: Are the document and edge collections looking alright? Can you get a graph result via the query editor in the web interface? (You need to return edges or paths in order to trigger this result display mode). Note that the graph viewer for named graphs shows a random start vertex and its neighborhood by default. You can change the start node, but not visualize the entire graph.

Comment: yes. I have updated the import commands.

Comment: Can you try the latest version (currently ArangoDB 3.3.7) and add a screenshot of what you see in the web interface?

Comment: Ok . Please give me sometime

Comment: Did same as previous. Please note I have updated the Questions with results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph viewer has a default limit of 250 nodes. This can be adjusted in the properties panel (open it with a click on the hamburger icon) in the section **Graph** in the field **Limit**:

[image: ArangoDB Graph Viewer Settings]

Set it to 2000, hit return and load the full graph and wait a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now  It shows all nodes but still 0 edges.

Comment: Are the edges actually connected to these vertices? Please verify the correctness of the *_from* and *_to* attributes. Also make sure that the color for edges isn't set to the background color (white). You could try a different browser and switch the renderer to check if it's a problem with a specific setting or browser.

Comment: There was a mistake in _from and _to attributes, The generated E-CA.json edges has from to with "V" suffix. Actually I had to create Vertices collection as "V" instead of "vertices".